# Can anyone explain the introduction of Rapid Dual Homing to me?what is the main function of rapid dual homing?

Tags: switch, network, redundancy, topology

I read some information about  Rapid Dual Homing  from JetNet 5020G,the figure below is the introduction of Rapid Dual Homing.

[image]

Honestly,i don't understand why can the rapid dual homing have multiple redundancies from its introduction,after i study it, i have some thinking and some questions

**Thinking**

A is other vendors ethernet switch,and B is the MSR ethernet switch,and both of them comprise a ring,so the main function of rapid dual homing is that let two different vendors switches be connected and work functionally without any problems.

Q1:
If my thinking is right,why can the connection of two rings ,which are combined with different vendors switches,have multiple redundancies?

Q2:The introduction says  " uplink can be auto-detected,and gathered into groups,each group path is sorted into primary,secondary and standby ",what does it have some relation with its figure?because i cannot understand this introduction from its figure.

Can anyone explain the introduction of Rapid Dual Homing to me ?thanks a lot

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Rapid Dual Homing* is Korenix's marketing term for redundant meshing of Ethernet with 'rapid' failover (50 ms for ERPS). It encompasses multiple standard protocols:

- ERPS V1 (Ethernet Ring Protection Switching V1)
- ERPS V2 (Ethernet Ring Protection Switching V2)
- RSTP (Rapid Spanning Tree Protocol)

See https://www.contradata.it/it/korenix-ethernet-switches-redundancy-at-all-levels

How it interacts with other vendors' devices depends in the configuration.

There's a lot of marketing bla, I think it's wise to look at the basic protocols to make a more educated choice. Generally, I'd recommend building a redundant tree for Ethernet instead of double rings or chains.

Comment: Can i ask that what is the meaning of " up link " in the introduction?

Comment: An uplink is a link towards the center of the network.

Comment: so the center of the network may be a switch too?

Comment: @user16266657 Yes, most likely a switch (or a pair of).

Comment: so can i say that the uplink  is actually the switch sends the signal to another switch

Comment: what does the "each group path is sorted into primary,secondary and standby" mean? what is the group path?